# What is the difference between || and | in R ?

Tags: r

I know that "||" means "or" in most programming languages, including R. But sometimes I see people using "|". And I am not entirely sure what it means. How is it different from "||" ?

Thanks

Answer (score 13):

To get to the help for the logical operators in R you have to do

```
?`|`
```

or

```
?`||`
```

Both of which take you to the appropriate help page http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Logic.html

You won't notice a difference until you either put a vector in, or something that doesn't evaluate properly:

```
> T|F
[1] TRUE
> T||F
[1] TRUE
```

But when you use a vector:

```
> c(T,T,F,F) || c(T,F,T,F)
[1] TRUE
> c(T,T,F,F) | c(T,F,T,F)
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

Similarly with `&` and `&&`:

```
> c(T,T,F,F) & c(T,F,T,F)
[1]  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
> c(T,T,F,F) && c(T,F,T,F)
[1] TRUE
```

So `|` and `&` compare elements in corresponding positions in the two vectors and uses that to populate a new logical vector. If one vector is shorter than the other, its elements get "[recycled](https://www.inkling.com/read/r-cookbook-paul-teetor-1st/chapter-5/recipe-5-3)" from the start:

```
> c(T, F, T, F) | c(T, T, F, F, T, F) #first 2 elements of left vector recycled
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
Warning message:
In c(T, F, T, F) | c(T, T, F, F, T, F) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
> c(T, F, T, F, T, F) | c(T, T, F, F, T, F) #what actually got evaluated
[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
```

Note that `||` and `&&` only look at the first element of the vectors, so for instance:

```
> c(T,T,T,T) && c(F,T,T,T) #only does T & F
[1] FALSE
> c(F,T,T,T) || c(F,T,T,T) #only does F | F
[1] FALSE
> c(T,F,F,F) && c(T,F,F,F) #only does T & T
[1] TRUE
> c(T,F,F,F) || c(F,F,F,F) #only does F | F
[1] TRUE
```

For inputs that can't be evaluated, `||` and `&&` are cleverer: they "shortcircuit" from left to right. If the left-hand input of `||` is `TRUE` (so the result must be `TRUE`) or the left-hand input of `&&` is `FALSE` (so the result must be `FALSE`) then right-hand input need not be evaluated.

```
> x
Error: object 'x' not found
> exists("x")
[1] FALSE
> F & x # evaluates right input, fails
Error: object 'x' not found
> F && x # skips right input, already knows result F
[1] FALSE
> T && x # can't skip right input, so fails
Error: object 'x' not found
> T | x
Error: object 'x' not found
> T || x # skips right input, already knows result T
[1] TRUE
```

This is useful if you want to check something safely:

```
> (x > 20)
Error: object 'x' not found
> exists("x") & (x > 20) # still evaluated right input, fails
Error: object 'x' not found
> exists("x") && (x > 20) # safe
[1] FALSE
```

Answer (score 11):

There are **three relevant differences** between the operators `&&`/`||` and `&`/`|`, which are explained in the [official documentation](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Logic.html). Here’s a summary:

#### 1. `&` and `|` are *vectorised*

This means that if you want to perform element-wise logical operations on vectors you should use `&` and `|`:

```
a = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE)
b = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE)

a | b
# [1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

a || b
# Error in a || b : 'length = 4' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
```

In previous versions of R, `a || b` (and `a && b`) did not cause an error. Instead, the operations silently truncated the output (only the first element was returned; before making this an error it briefly caused a warning in R 4.2).

#### 2. `&&` and `||` are *short-circuited*

Short-circuiting means that the right-hand side of the expression is only evaluated if the left-hand side does not already determine the outcome. Pretty much every programming language does this for conditional operations, since it leads to handy idioms when writing `if` conditions, e.g.:

```
if (length(x) > 0L && x[1L] == 42) …
```

This code relies on short-circuiting: without it, the code would fail if `x` is empty, since the right-hand side attempts to access a non-existent element. Without short-circuiting, we would have to use nested `if` blocks, leading to more verbose code:

```
if (length(x) > 0L) {
    if (x[1L] == 42) …
}
```

As a general rule, inside a conditional expression (`if`, `while`) you should *always* use `&&` and `||`, even if short-circuiting isn’t required: it’s more idiomatic, and leads to more uniform code.

#### 3. `&` and `|` can perform *bitwise arithmetic*

In many (most?) programming languages, `&` and `|` actually perform bitwise arithmetic instead of Boolean arithmetic. That is, for two integers `a` and `b`, `a & b` calculates the *bitwise and*, and `a | b` calculates the *bitwise or*. For Boolean values there’s no difference between bitwise and logical operations; but for arbitrary integers, the result differs. For instance, `1 | 2 == 3` in most programming languages.

However, this is *not* true for R: R coerces numeric arguments of `&` and `|` to logical values and performs Boolean arithmetic.

… except when both arguments are of type `raw`:

```
c(1, 3) | c(2, 4)
# [1] TRUE TRUE

as.raw(c(1, 3)) | as.raw(c(2, 4))
# [1] 03 07
```

It is worth noting that the operations `!` (logical negation) and `xor` also perform bitwise arithmetic when called with `raw` arguments.