# How to stop the annoying warnings output by reticulate in R

Tags: python, r, pandas, reticulate

I am trying to read a `pickle` data in R, I have following R code:

```
library(reticulate)
pd <- suppressMessages(import("pandas"))
hubs.data <- suppressWarnings(pd$read_pickle("input.pickle"))
```

The code is worked well, but its will output a warnning:

```
sys:1: FutureWarning: pandas.Float64Index is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.Index with the appropriate dtype instead.
sys:1: FutureWarning: pandas.Int64Index is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.Index with the appropriate dtype instead.
sys:1: FutureWarning: pandas.UInt64Index is deprecated and will be removed from pandas in a future version. Use pandas.Index with the appropriate dtype instead.
```

This warning will show when exculate any other R code line after this. I want to stop it.

I have tried:

```
pd <- suppressWarnings(import("pandas"))
# or
pd <- suppressMessages(import("pandas"))
```

But the `suppressWarnings/suppressMessages` seem not work

Comment: The warnings may be annoying, but they are *informative*.  if you achieve your immediate goal, then at some point in he future, your code will fail, possibly without explanation.  Is that what you want to happen?

Comment: Yeah @Limey, Its useful message, but Its will print every times when I exec other R code lines after `pd <- import("pandas")`, its so annoying.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control Python warnings within Python / through `reticulate`; this is basically what `reticulate::py_suppress_warnings()` does.

For testings purposes we first set up a reprex to always show warnings, otherwise `trigger_warning()` would only warn once, during the first occurrence. Then we'll suppress it with `warnings$simplefilter("ignore")` when calling from R (or with `warnings.simplefilter("ignore")` from Python).

Python warning categories and filter actions along with examples can be found from https://docs.python.org/3/library/warnings.html

```r
library(reticulate)
# use specific conda env
# use_condaenv("py311") 

# change Python(!) warning action from `once` to `always` for testing;
# create a dummy function to trigger FutureWarning
py_run_string('
import warnings

warnings.simplefilter("always")
def trigger_warning():
  warnings.warn("a future warning", FutureWarning)
  return 42
')

# triggering a warning:
py$trigger_warning()
#> <string>:6: FutureWarning: a future warning
#> [1] 42

# control Pyhon warnings through reticulate:
warnings <- import("warnings")

# ignore / suppress:
warnings$simplefilter("ignore")
py$trigger_warning()
#> [1] 42
```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your help, but it seem not work, my code is ` warnings <- import("warnings")\n
 warnings$simplefilter("always")\n
 pd <- import("pandas")`

Comment: @zhang, `"always"`  action always prints warnings, in the example above it was used to explicitly enable warnings so we could then test suppressing. What you seem to be after is `"ignore"` action. Edited in an attempt to make it more clear.

Comment: ，Thats work well, thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The goal is not to suppress all warnings but only those I don't want to see: change the regexp inside `testw_xxx_msg <-any(grepl("a warning message",w) )`

```
My_suppressWarnings <- function (fct, ...) {

  tryCatch(
    withCallingHandlers (
      {
        fct(...)
      }, warning=function(w) {
        testw_1st_msg <-any(grepl("will be removed from pandas",w) )
        testw_2nd_msg <-any(grepl("other warning message",w) )
         
        if (testw_1st_msg || testw_2nd_msg ) {
          invokeRestart("muffleWarning")
        }    else {
          conditionMessage(w)
        }
      }),
    error = function(e) {
      print(e)
    }
  )
}
```

And try
`My_suppressWarnings(pd$read_pickle("input.pickle"))`

In my R projects I have some functions like that one which works, for `dplyr` and `ggplot2`, but here without reproducible example it's not easy.

Look also that: https://r-critique.com/how_to_muffle_warnings_and_to_restart

You also can look for similar solution in the Python side.

Comment: OP already tried `suppressWarnings()`, without success. Your function won’t work either. — Another point, inside `if` you should use always use `||` (and `&&`), not `|` (or `&`). The latter two are vectorised, which makes no sense inside an `if` conditional.

Comment: Double or simple or: it's not as simple as that :P 
https://r-lang.com/or-in-r/ and  https://stackoverflow.com/a/16027891

Comment: I am [very well aware of the differences](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22251946/1968) (and both explanations you’ve posted are woefully incomplete), and yet the rule is clear: inside an `if` conditional, you should *always* use the `||` and `&&`. Using `|` or `&` at best signals a misleading intent, and at worst performs the incorrect operation.

Comment: Hi phili_b and Konrad Rudolph, Thank your all for your kindly help, but the My_suppressWarnings() seems not work in my environment, It appears that this warning is not thrown by R, and once it occurs, it will be printed to the terminal when executing unrelated statements subsequently.

Comment: @Konrad Rudolph: In this case of simple `if` with strings, and many cases you're right, double or is better, but not *always*: in case of vectorized or bitwise  comparison. (Even if in my answer it's rendered in fact the same).

Comment: @phili_b But `if` (and `while`) *cannot deal with vectorised comparisons!* That’s what I meant by “performs the incorrect operation”, and that is *the* reason for always using non-vectorised operations inside conditions.